# clear values from FORM after submit with wrong data

Tags: php

I have problem with my form. When i sumbit form witch correct data everything is ok. Problem is when I send data with wrong data. For example when "Password" and "PasswordAgain" dont match. All data from my forms are cleared.

I have MVC architecture. In view I have

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="Name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Jméno:</label>
  <input id="name" type="text" required name="name" class="form-control col-md-3" placeholder="Jméno" <?php if (isset($_POST['name'])) echo(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));?>>
</div>
```

in Controller I have

```
if (isset($_POST['addUser']))
{
  try
  {
    if (empty($_POST['nickname']))
    {
      $this->addMessage('the nickname must be filled in');
      $counter = 1;
    }
    if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
      $this->addMessage('the name must be filled in');
      $counter = 1;
    }
    if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 5) {
      $this->addMessage('the password must be filled in');
      $counter = 1;
    }
    if (($_POST['password']) != ($_POST['passwordAgain'])) {
      $this->addMessage('passwords must match.');
      $counter = 1;
    }
    if ($counter == 0)
    {
      $UsersManager->insertUser($_POST['nickname'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['passwordAgain'], $_POST['about']);
      $this->addMessage('User was succesfully aded');
      $this->reroute('userAdd');
    }
  }
```

How I can solve it correctly?  I need form, where my data will remain after sumbit with wrong data.

Answer (score 0):

The values you have entered in form will always clear on page refresh. But if input has some error then keep that input array in a separate variable(Let's say it **old**) and pass to view again. In view, it will check whether **old** has value for particular field, if yes then enter value to field else that field remain blank.

Basically, this is how most of framework do it.

In Controller:

```
   if ($counter == 0) {
        $UsersManager->insertUser($_POST['nickname'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['passwordAgain'], $_POST['about']);
        $this->addMessage('User was succesfully aded');
        $this->reroute('userAdd');
    } else {
        $old = $_POST;
    }
```

Pass this **$old** variable to view.

In view:

```
<input type="text" name="nickname" value="<?php echo empty($old['nickname']) ? '' : $old['nickname']; ?>">
```

This is just a basic code to make you understand because I don't have idea about how actual code look like.